# SonarQube Individual Scans in Multi-Project Configurations

Tags: ant, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I have a project has the following format:

```
Application A:
--Module 1
--Module 2
--Module 3
```

I build and manage each module individually, but all of them are aggregated into a single system.  I'd like use Sonar to view code analysis at the 'Application A' level, but the scans will run individually with CI builds for each module.  Is there a way to configure the sonar runner to achieve this?  I tried configuring the modules appropriately, but if I first run a scan of module 1 and then a scan of module 2, the project only shows module 2 in the web UI.  I'm not sure if there's a way around it and building all projects at the same time is not currently feasible.  Any thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Another way for me to frame this question is how to, given a project in SonarQube, to do independent analysis of each module and have their results pushed individually as opposed to doing a build/scan of all source code.